# Is there a way to write and retrive code snippets on a textarea whilst not losing the structure?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a simple code manager for myself. I have a form with a `textarea` where I write my code and that gets stored in a database. - the storing part is fine, I did it by escaping the content and striping the special html characters, so that part is fine.

What I cant do is maintain the structure. if I write this

```
body{
  color: red;
 }
```

I get all that in one line - so so I could not capture the line brake. Then I found that `textarea` uses `\n` to indicate line brake, so I did this `nl2br($_POST['mytextarea']);`. This gives my the line brakes but not the indentations.

I tried using tinymce as an editor but I felt it's too much for what I needed.

So is there a way to capture the line brakes and spaces from a `textarea`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do any encoding on the data before storing it.  You should only sanitize it to prevent injection.  You should encode it for *display* (mainly use `htmlspecialchars` on it).

If you are displaying it in another container (not a textarea), you can add the `white-space: pre` rule to it, or just use `<pre>` tags to have it display whitespace as-is.  If you are displaying it in a `<textarea>`, it should already do that and you are stripping out spaces at some point when you should not be.

Answer (score 0):

the structure is probably being stored. try outputting the text to a text area.

Comment: @Explosion explained it better.